# What are "drag-and-drop-####.txt" files?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, ubuntu-gnome

I'm not exactly sure when this started, but I think it was after an upgrade to 18.04. In my `Documents` folder I get 10-20 of these `drag-and-drop-####.txt` files in a day. This is extremely annoying and obviously something is wrong.

The file contains multiple lines saying

> [CFxDSAPIDragAndDropHelper::AcceptDrop] Drag And Drop Override enabled

I can't find ANY information on this through google and I'm at a loss.
Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you for your time!

System: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, Gnome 3.28.2, 64 bits.

Comment: I changed the title to improve its searchability.

Comment: @zx485 that title could scared anyone :O

Comment: If you think so... I do not object...

Answer (score 1):

The line in your file supplies some information. [DSAPI](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/tools/c/5.0.3/api503ug.nsf/85255d56004d2bfd85255b1800631684/aad371dc1de6cad58525687b0054da41) is probably a hint to the Domino Web Server Application Interface, which is an interface for the Domino Web Server. Do you remember installing something that makes use of this web server? Do you have an application running this web server? Can you find it running in some task manager such as [htop](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/htop/)?

If so, do you need it? Do you know how to [set it up](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/conf_settingupadominoserverasawebserver_t.html)?

It seems like the domino web server used to be owned by [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/conf_thedominowebserver_c.html) who seem to have sold it to HCL Technologies. Maybe some older IBM software is still using it.

DragAndDropHelper::AcceptDrop looks lik the Java function AcceptDrop of Class DragAndRopHelper does something here. This is in line with the Domino web server using Java internally.

I believe you will need someone with knowledge of the Domino Web Server to help you.

I hope that helps in narrowing down what goes wrong.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Thank you Ace28, I will look into this Domino Web Server. With the information you gave me I suspect my stock trading software because it runs of Java script and I run it every day. Thank you very much and have a great day.

Comment: Yep, that might be it. Let us know if that track solved your problem :)